# Blank page with PHP / MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a snippet of code recycled from another location and the original works fine but the modified one just gives me a blank page. I have tried commenting out sections in hopes of isolating the problem but I keep hitting a road block. I know it is something simple and something I am overlooking but I my brain hurts now and figured I would post it on here while I went outside to scream at passing cars to relieve some frustration.

```
    <TITLE> Add Item </TITLE>
<?php

include("dbc.php");

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
        $material = $_POST['material'];
        $dimmention = $_POST['dimmention'];
        $size = $_POST['length'];
        $color = $_POST['color'];

        if(!$material)
                {
                echo "Error: Material is a required field. Please fill it.";
                exit();
                }

        $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO list (mat, date, dim, size, color)
        VALUES ('$material',NOW (),'$dimmention','$size','$color')",$connect);
        echo "<b>Thank you! Item added Successfully!<br>You'll be redirected to Home Page after (4) Seconds";
        echo "<meta http-equiv=Refresh content=4;url=index.php>";

        }
else
        {
        ?>
        <br>
        <h3>::Add Item</h3>
        <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER[PHP_SELF] ?>">
        Material (Alum, Galv, Steel): <input name="material" size="6" maxlength="6">
        <br>
        Dimentions (1 x 2 Patio, 2 x 2 090): <input name="dimmention" size="50" maxlength="100">
        <br>
        Size (24, 30, 15): <input name="length" size="5" maxlength="5">
        <br>
        Color (bronze, white, MF): <input name="color" size="6" maxlength="6">
        <br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add Item">
        </form>
        <?
        }

?>
```

Thanks to all who can help.

Comment: Always check your server web logs first. It will tell you what the problem is.

Comment: Put ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL); after the first <?php and see what the error is...

Comment: This is an accident waiting to happen.

Comment: I also recommend using PDO or mysqli, as mysql_* functions are depreciated.

Comment: Please, before you write **any** more SQL interfacing code, you must read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) to avoid severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) like the ones you have here. Also, `mysql_query` should not be used in new applications. It's a deprecated interface that's being removed from future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and is a safer way to compose queries. `$_POST` data never goes directly in a query.

Comment: Panama Jack: I went and checked. It pointed me to the problem which was solved with MichaelRushton's solution. Thank you.

Strawberry: Please Explain? I am being forced to learn all this at virtual gunpoint so any help helps.

Laurent: I read that but when using another person's code I try to stick to what they do and then rework it. Much appreciated!

@MichaelRushton: Thanks... You and Panama lead me to the conclusion. Turning them on fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My initial assumption is that you have [short open tags](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) turned off in your `ini` file. Change the bottom of the page from this:

```
<?

  }

?>
```

To this:

```
<?php

  }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're likely getting a PHP error.

Try adding this code right before your include statement:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
include('dbc.php');
```

Comment: This is going into my snippet code book for future troubleshooting. Thanks @Rob